# SparkR and Packages

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

How do one call packages from spark to be utilized for data operations with R?

example i am trying to access my test.csv in hdfs as below

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/opt/spark14")
library(SparkR)
sc <- sparkR.init(master="local")
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
flights <- read.df(sqlContext,"hdfs://sandbox.hortonWorks.com:8020     /user/root/test.csv","com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true")
```

but getting error as below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class for data  source: com.databricks.spark.csv
```

i tried loading the csv  package by below option

```
Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3')
```

but getting the below error during loading sqlContext

```
Launching java with spark-submit command /opt/spark14/bin/spark-submit   --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3 /tmp/RtmpuvwOky  /backend_port95332e5267b 
Error: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/tmp/RtmpuvwOky/backend_port95332e5267b
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like by setting `SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS` you are overriding the default value, which is `sparkr-shell`. You could probably do the same thing and just append sparkr-shell to the end of your SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS. This is seems unnecessarily complex compared to depending on jars so I've created a JIRA to track this issue (and I'll try and a fix if the SparkR people agree with me) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8506 .

Note: another option would be using the sparkr command + `--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3` since that should work.

Comment: Thanks Holden.I am trying to execute this script using Rstudio.I was trying to identify the syntax to be associated for the two options viz adding spark-shell to ens of SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS and running the --packages command.Any insights to these syntax?

Comment: The right way to setup SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS is to do something like  `Sys.setenv(SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS="--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3 sparkr-shell")`.  I have a PR open to add this to the official documentation at https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/6916