# Use Spark package with RStudio

Tags: r, apache-spark

I would like to use the [spark-csv](http://spark-packages.org/package/databricks/spark-csv) package with SparkR using RStudio. It works perfectly with the SparkR shell but I didn't find any way to include it in a RStudio session.

Any idea how to do it ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "[...] to include it in a RStudio session"?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you are not able to load the package in RStudio ?

Comment: @psteelk yes I was not able to load the package on RStudio. I actually found an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30952039/sparkr-and-packages). The problem is that I need to build an assembly jar, which is not really convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem, look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870379/loading-com-databricks-spark-csv-via-rstudio) question

The solution given by Pragith works perfect without building the assembly jar: run

```
Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"--packages" "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3" "sparkr-shell"')
```

before

```
library(SparkR)
```

And you can read the .csv file from within RStudio.  In the same way, you should be able to include all other packages you want.